# Create a QListView of QGraphicsView objects

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qlistview, qabstractlistmodel

I want to be able to create a vertical list of items that will give a similar appearance as to what you see in PowerPoint where it shows a vertical list of tiles that represent each slide.

I believe using a `QListView` with a `QAbstractListModel` is the right way to go about this.  My `QAbstractListModel` subclass contains a `QList` of `QGraphicsViews`.  So, each tile (or slide) is a `QGraphicsView`.  I've spent a lot of time trying to find a similar example on the internet and I've also been using Qt's example but haven't had much luck.

Here is my model class...

I can get the "ADDING" message in `addgvw`, but I can't get the "HERE" message in `data`.

```
myDataModel::myDataModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

QVariant myDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }

    cGraphicsViewWrapper* gvw = GVWrapperList.at(index.row());

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        qDebug() << "HERE";

        //Return the QGraphicsView object to display
        return QVariant::fromValue(gvw->gvwView());
    }

    return QVariant();
}

int myDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);

    return GVWrapperList.size();
}

void myDataModel::addgvw(int role, cGraphicsViewWrapper& gvw)
{
    if (role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), GVWrapperList.size(), GVWrapperList.size());

        GVWrapperList.append(&gvw);

        qDebug() << "ADDING " << GVWrapperList.size() << rowCount();

        endInsertRows();
    }
}
```

This is how I use my model class...

In my constructor of my widget class I call

```
myGVWWidget::myGVWWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::myPlottingWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Model = new myDataModel(this);

    ui->GWVListView->setModel(Model);

    connectAllSignals();
}
```

...then in my function that creates new tiles, after a tile is created I call...

```
Model->addChart(Qt::EditRole, *gvw);
```

In the end, my widget is empty :(

EDIT: I want to add, since I think it's likely I may get asked, for numerous reasons, I'm not interested in converting to a QPixMap and displaying an image for a tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `QAbstractItemView` and friends expect `DisplayRole` data to be a QString and nothing else:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum

Your best bet will be using `QListWidget` which does have a way to use `QWidget` for items: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget

Also, using `QGraphicsView` carry a huge overhead. `QGraphicsView` is a really complicated widget and `QGraphicsScene` it needs is even more complicated. Be prepared for slow performance if you have more than a handful of items in the list.

You are really overkilling this. :)

Comment: Yes, I am greatly aware of the overhead.  I had originally used a QListWidget with my ~20 items in it and the performance was great, so I know it won't be an issue.  But I had other issues with it, like the list scrolling backwards and not being able to select items.